# Breeze one-to-many navigation property not fully materialised without noTracking

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Not wanting to clog up the question, I've left out most of the code but I can put it in if it helps.

using Breeze 1.4.9 and Breeze.angular v.0.9.0

I have a simple model: a `ChartDefinition` has a single `DataQuery`, and that `DataQuery` has some parameters.

I have a breeze query:

```
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from("ChartDefinitions")
                .expand(["DataQuery","DataQuery.Parameters"]);
                //.noTracking();
```

I can see the server's response (i've replaced most of the simple properties with '...'):

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"itaprm4.Domain.ChartDefinition, itaprm4","Id":1,"Title":"FirstChart", ... ,
  "DataQuery":
        {"$id":"2","$type":"itaprm4.Domain.DataQuery, itaprm4","Id":1, ... ,
                 "Parameters":
            [{"$id":"3","$type":"itaprm4.Domain.DataQueryParameter, itaprm4","Id":1, ...}]
        }
 }
,{"$id":"4","$type":"itaprm4.Domain.ChartDefinition, itaprm4","Id":2,"Title":"ProjectBudgets", ... ,
  "DataQuery":
        {"$id":"5","$type":"itaprm4.Domain.DataQuery, itaprm4","Id":2, ... ,
         "Parameters":[]
        }
 },
{"$id":"6","$type":"itaprm4.Domain.ChartDefinition, itaprm4","Id":3,"Title":"ProjectActuals", ... ,
 "DataQuery":
        {"$id":"7","$type":"itaprm4.Domain.DataQuery, itaprm4","Id":3, ... ,
         "Parameters":
            [{"$id":"8","$type":"itaprm4.Domain.DataQueryParameter, itaprm4","Id":2,"DataQueryId":3, ...},
             {"$id":"9","$type":"itaprm4.Domain.DataQueryParameter, itaprm4","Id":3,"DataQueryId":3, ...}
            ]
        }
}]
```

After the entities have been materialised though, that last `DataQuery` object ($id:7) has a parameters array **but**, it only contains the last parameter ($id:9).

Digging around in `breeze.debug` I saw that `noTracking` causes the materialisation code down a different path so tacked the `noTracking()` option onto the query. This results in **both** the paramters appearing in the materlised `Parameters` array. (I'm assuming that since breeze *can* materialise the object graph correctly, there isn't anything wrong with the code on the server? so I haven't included it in this question...)

I would simply keep the `noTracking` option on but, I'm registering a constructor function with breeze and it doesn't get called if `noTracking` is on.

```
store.registerEntityTypeCtor('ChartDefinition', ChartDefinition);
```

Is there something else I need to do to get the parameters array filled without the `noTracking` option?

Edit:
Another observation : without the `noTracking` option, the `DataQueryParameter` with $id:8 actually ends up in the parameters array of the `DataQuery` with $id:5

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this had a lot to do with what was on the server!

Our nHibernate set-up was using a different name for the `DataQueryId` property on the `DataQuery` class (the devs in the team tell me there were some issues with updating entities and doing this solved that issue):

```
<class name="DataQuery" table="sys_DataQuery" dynamic-update="true"  >
  <id name="Id" column="DataQueryId" type="int" unsaved-value="0">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>

  ...

  <bag name="Parameters" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="DataQueryId"/>
    <one-to-many class="DataQueryParameter"/>
  </bag>
</class>



<class name="DataQueryParameter" table="sys_DataQueryParameter" dynamic-update="true"  >
  ...
  <property name="DataQueryId" type="int" not-null="true" insert="true" update="true" />
  ...
</class>
```

With matching identifiers in the class definitions.

Changing the `Id` to `DataQueryId` solved my problem:

```
<class name="DataQuery" table="sys_DataQuery" dynamic-update="true"  >
  <id name="DataQueryId" column="DataQueryId" type="int" unsaved-value="0">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
...
```

This seems to make sense; how would breeze know to match `DataQueryParamter.DataQueryId` to `DataQuery.Id` but, I have no idea why Breeze could correctly materialise the object graph with noTracking switched on though?